# unit tests in python with large __init__ code for class file

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to understand unit testing in python. If I have a class with a large `__init__` function, and I am writing unit-tests for member functions of this class, which need to refer `self` object, what's the best way to go about it?

As a follow up several of these functions could be `@staticmethods`, but we have decided to stay pythonic, and keep `self.func_calls` instead so is there an easier way to write test-code for such functions?

Comment: How would you test a class with a small `__init__` function? I assume that you are using this class in your program. A Unit Test 'uses' a class in the same way, but asserts something about the results.

Comment: Why would it be easier not to have static methods? Isn't testing it actually easier, since you don't have to instantiate an object? Regarding the 1st point, what does "large" means? (memory usage? time? both?) If you want to test functions, you're going to have to instantiate the object at some point. Perhaps if it's too "large" it should be several classes instead of one?

Comment: I agree, I did have `@staticmethods` but seems like it's not the pythonic way to go, and it's suggested to call them via objects regardless... read a stackoverflow post regarding the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instantiating your class takes a long time, and multiple tests can use the same instance, you can use `setUpClass`

```
import unittest

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.obj = MyClass()

    def test_stuff(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.obj.thing, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

By unit testing I'll assume you mean the `unittest` library in Python. You can instantiate your class in the `setUp()` method for each test class. Like so:

```
class Test_MyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        my_args = get_my_args()
        m = MyClass(my_args)

    def test_my_method(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.m.my_method(some_input), some_result)
```

Comment: The unittest test-runner will run setUp() for every test method in the test class. This will not be more efficient, but it does lead to cleaner test code.